# Sending SMS in background on pressing key on hardware in android

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, sms

I have developed an application integrated with BLE based Beacon.

We have a feature that sends an SOS message in the emergency case from user mobile automatically when we press the key on BLE Beacon.

We have used **SEND_SMS** permission.

But my application could not be approved due to permission.
Should I change my permission? or anything need to change on Application or Google play console.

Answer (score -1):

At https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10208820/use-of-sms-or-call-log-permission-groups?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-sms-and-call-log-permissions%2Cexceptions you have a list of exceptions.

> Physical safety/emergency alerts to send SMS
>
> Apps that send SMS alerts in emergency situations

is such an exception you could try to apply for.

Comment: I tried with `Physical safety/emergency alert apps (e.g. senior safety)` option but still rejected @Emil

Comment: I have written instruction `Hi, 
We will be using MyTag Application with BLE based hardware. 
We have introduced a new SOS feature that sends an SOS message when we press the button 3 times from the BLE hardware, SMS will be sent from the user mobile in the background.
This way we are sending SMS from the user mobile on pressing the hardware button 3 times.
  `